# Dynamic width with fixed column

Tags: html, css, layout

I am trying to create a page that has a width that adjusts to the screen with a fixed width column on the right. So for example:

```
|                    |          |
|-------Content------|--Column--|
|                    |          |

       |             |          |
       |---Content---|--Column--|
       |             |          |

    |                |          |
    |-----Content----|--Column--|
    |                |          |
```

http://www.reddit.com/ would be a good example of this.
Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This blog is pretty useful for grabbing complex layouts.

[ultimate-2-column-right-menu-pixels](http://matthewjamestaylor.com/blog/ultimate-2-column-right-menu-pixels.htm)

Answer (score 1):

this is essentially what reddit does: http://jsfiddle.net/pxfunc/rCG84/

the side div 1.) is above content in the html, 2.) is set to `float:right;`, and 3.) given a specific width (`width:300px`)

```
<div id="side"></div>
<div id="content"></div>
```

the content div will adjust with the window size